# Wordpress : is it possible to connect $wpdb class into other database?

Tags: wordpress

the question is related to wordpress coding only. If it possible, the code solution is able to use inside a wordpress blog.

$wpdb is only work with database that been declare in wp-config. So it possible to clone $wpdb then use the clone to access different database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a new instance:

```
$db2 = new wpdb('root','root','test','localhost');
```

Comment: thanks i have check your question and it's so true. i got this article http://ilfilosofo.com/blog/2006/09/08/integrating-vanilla-forum-and-wordpress-themes/ . Maybe somebody will need this link when they search for wpdb topic