# PHP : substitute to wpdb class in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

wpdb class in wordpress is used for making connection to database.

is there any substitute to this class in PHP repository?

So i can access different database then the original database that have been initiate in wp-config ?

Comment: Why do you ask twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542877/wordpress-is-it-possible-to-connect-wpdb-class-into-other-database

Comment: i believe i'm not asking twice. it's different question for the same purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wordpress is developped using PHP, I suppose you could use any PHP functions/classes, as long as the corresponding extension is installed on your server.

See the [**Database Extensions**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.php) section of the manual for a list of extensions that can be used to connect to different kinds of database systems.

If you are using MySQL, I would suggest the **[mysqli][2]** extension -- at least if installed on your server ; it's more recent, and support more features, than the old [mysql][3] one.

**[PDO](http://fr.php.net/pdo)** can be a good choice too -- and works with both MySQL and other database systems.