# Connecting to an external database from within Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to connect to and import data into a WordPress 3.5.1 page template from an external database which is hosted on the same localhost server.

I've Googled this extensively and have come up with the most preferred solution for this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Import Sign data
*/
?>

<?php echo "Import Sign Data Page<br>"; ?>

<?php
$mydb = new wpdb('myname', 'mypassword', 'mydb', 'localhost');
$mydb->show_errors();

$signs = $mydb->get_results("SELECT * FROM signs");
print_r($signs);
foreach ($signs as $sign) {
    echo $sign->title . '<br />';
}

?>
```

The code above only gives me the first echo, 'Import Sign Data Page' and nothing else. No errors, nothing. I've checked all my syntax many times now. Can any see where I might have gone wrong here or perhaps suggest some debugging tips?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Using the wpdb class is [by definition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) only going to work with the installed wordpress database. You should use whatever functions that pertain to your external database.

Comment: Thanks Jermey, but there's many documented instances of wpdb being used (along with is methods) on external databases, even here on stackoverflow ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542877/wordpress-is-it-possible-to-connect-wpdb-class-into-other-database

Comment: OK, so the code above works great as is. The problem was I got my connect args from an outdated local script! Once I pulled the connect script down from the server I had the right name, pw, etc. I was thrown because the script didn't present a connect error, but then I took Jermey's advice and tried with a stock php/mysql connect script with a die statement on the connect and that revealed the error. So I found out that both methods work from within Wordpress.